# Task not serializable : Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

My spark job is throwing Task not serializable at runtime. Can anyone tell me if what i am doing wrong here?

```
@Component("loader")
    @Slf4j
public class LoaderSpark implements SparkJob {
    private static final int MAX_VERSIONS = 1;

    private final AppProperties props;


    public LoaderSpark(
            final AppProperties props
    ) {
        this.props = props;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(SparkSession spark, final String... args) throws IOException {

        HBaseUtil hBaseUtil = new HBaseUtil(props);

        byte[][] prefixes = new byte[][]{toBytes("document"),
                toBytes("dataSource"),
                toBytes("hold:")};

        Filter filter = new MultipleColumnPrefixFilter(prefixes);

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily(toBytes("data"));
        scan.setCaching(100000);
        scan.setMaxVersions(MAX_VERSIONS);
        scan.setFilter(filter);


        JavaRDD<TestMethod> mapFileJavaRDD
                = hBaseUtil.createScanRdd(spark, "TestTable", scan).mapPartitions(tuple -> {

            return StreamUtils.asStream(tuple)
                    .map(this::extractResult)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .iterator();

        });


        Dataset<TestMethod> testDataset = spark.createDataset(mapFileJavaRDD.rdd(), bean(TestMethod.class));
        testDataset.limit(100);

    }

    private TestMethod extractResult(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> resultTuple) {


        TestMethod.TestMethodBuilder testBuilder = TestMethod.builder();
        Result result;
        result = resultTuple._2();
        CdfParser cdfParser = new CdfParser();

        List<String> holdingId = new ArrayList<>();

        testBuilder.dataSource(Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),
                Bytes.toBytes("dataSource"))));
        testBuilder.document(cdfParser.fromXml(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),
                Bytes.toBytes("document"))));

        NavigableMap<byte[], byte[]> familyMap = result.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes("data"));
        for (byte[] bQunitifer : familyMap.keySet()) {

            if (Bytes.toString(bQunitifer).contains("hold:")) {

                LOG.info(Bytes.toString(bQunitifer));
                holdingId.add(Bytes.toString(bQunitifer));

            }
        }
        testBuilder.holding(holdingId);

        return testBuilder.build();
    }

}
```

HERE is the stacktrace:

```
  2020-04-29 12:48:59,837 INFO  [Thread-4]o.a.s.d.y.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
        at org.oclc.googlelinks.spark.SpringSparkJob.main(SpringSparkJob.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:694)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:798)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:797)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:797)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.mapPartitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.mapPartitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at org.oclc.googlelinks.spark.job.LoaderSpark.run(LoaderSpark.java:79)
        at org.oclc.googlelinks.spark.SpringSparkJob.run(SpringSparkJob.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: implements Serializable is used for saving state of an object LoaderSpark is definitely not a bean to save state of

Comment: any idea why it fails with Task not serializable . I removed the Serializable from LoaderSpark.

Comment: it needs getter and setter for all of your Object fields in order to serialize and de-serialize

Comment: there should be more errors logs as in which class is not serializable can you post that

Answer (score 0):

try adding getter and setters for `props`

```
public void setProps(AppProperties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }

    public AppProperties getProps() {
        return props;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you have kept the implement Serializable

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function extractResult  static . In order to call a static method, you don’t need to serialize the class, you need the declaring class to be reachable by the classloader (and it is the case, as the jar archives can be shared among driver and workers).

Thanks to https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/22/using-non-serializable-objects-in-apache-spark/